# Can Visual Studio 2017 RC auto-update to the official release?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

If you install `Visual Studio 2017 RC` (or `Visual Studio 2017 RC.2`), will it then auto-update to the official release once it is available? Or will you have to uninstall it and then install the official version?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/supportvs2017rc/

Just in case if you dont get answer here, try to chat in the official site of link. The support team addresses you. At the moment the support desk is closed. I attempted to ask support desk. No luck

Comment: @Pri, I've read that page three times. It does not state that RC can be updated to the upcoming *official* version. The information is ambiguous as it only states that the *product* itself will get updates. Now, is the RC the same product as the official version or not? Unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:

Open Visual Studio 2017 RC *-> Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Update*

It will first update the updater (yes that is possible :)

After that you can update to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017

Comment: A small PS, I tried from a 15.0.26228.10 yesterday, and it did NOT offer any of the two newer. Today it DOES offer the new 15.1.26403.00 though. I'm not sure why (no boot or anything), but if anyone do not see an expected update, patience might be the cure. ;)

Answer (score 4):

### RTM/RTW is out now. It auto-updates as expected.

History:

There is no official statement. Barring any issues where the installer would not be able to update Visual Studio, I assume that Microsoft will try to update the RC to final when possible and when licensed accordingly.

In the past there have been installer bugs which required a clean slate to upgrade, I suspect that Microsoft is keeping silent on this subject as they currently cannot foresee whether they may have to break the auto-update before the final version is released.

Answer (score 1):

Open the installer of your vs 2017 RC.
The installer will be updated, and then click Update on your version.
Worked for me this way.